# Is there any regenerating sticker source?

Tags: godus

Is there any regenerating sticker source?  Is it possible to leave your game in a "stuck until paid real money" state if you put pink stickers towards iron-age chests before getting ocean sculpting?

Comment: I take it this is about the mobile version? Because the PC version has no real money bits.

Comment: yep, iPad version

Answer (score 2):

(Someone may have to confirm this for the mobile version)

In the PC version, new chests occasionally spawn after/during a thunderstorm.

Alternately, once you've colonized most of the first world, send the occasional couple dozen believers to their doom in the fiery doom pit for gems, then buy sticker packs with the gems.

**UPDATE**: According to comments, the mobile version does not in fact have the Fiery Doom Pit to throw followers into.

Comment: I can confirm that new chests spawn occasionally in the mobile version, but very slowly. No idea if it's related to storms. I haven't seen more than a couple new ones a day. I guess you get stickers from voyages, but I've been stuck on "More voyages coming soon" ever since the tutorial voyage, with no indication of when "soon" might be.

Comment: @Josh Thanks for confirming -- I'm a bit hesitant to shell out money for the mobile version given how disappointing the PC version has been so far. Does it have the Pit Of Doom ?

Comment: Don't know, I haven't gotten that far - that's a late game thing, I assume?

Comment: (Honestly the mobile game is pretty, but disappointing. If you want to get enough belief to do much you have to open the game several times a day just to manually collect belief from every abode. That's not a game, that's a chore. And buying belief with real cash is impractically expensive. )

Comment: @Josh Nope, it's pretty much the first thing you find, before the boat even. It just isn't terribly useful until late game because every believer you sacrifice grants one gem and incurs a massive happiness penalty as well as a severe debuff on the reproduction rate of the building he or she came from.

Comment: then no, not on mobile. And I just read on the official website that voyages on mobile are disabled indefinitely. No explanation given.

Comment: I used the pit of doom a lot on PC; just sacrifice tons of people at once, and then dot beautify in small patches around lots of built plots (cities, abodes, farms, mines, etc) and you'll get the happiness back up in no time. But yeah, pit of doom is PC exclusive as a way to generate gems, so that you don't have a paid mechanic on a paid game.